# How can I set the publisher name in my signed jar file, using a self-signed certificate?

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate, signed-applet

I've compiled my applet, created a jar file, generated a keystore db with keytool, signed the jar with jarsigner, and exported the public key cert with keytool.

Now when I run my applet in the browser it does work, after prompting me if I'm sure I want it to run.

The problem is it says "Publisher: UNKNOWN" in the box. Is there anyway I can set that to my alias, since I coded the applet?

Comment: Can you show us the steps you have used while signing your applet ?

Answer (score 6):

A 'self signed' certificate is not worth the bits it is written on.  If you can make a certificate that claims it is you, I can just as easily forge one.

That is why the JRE lists the publisher as 'unknown'.  It does not matter who they *claim* to be, it is ignored unless the certificate has been verified by a trusted authority.

Comment: I am new to code signing. I believe I am doing everything correctly by following oracle's documentation strictly, but i am just not confident. Is there a way to test the results with a self cert? I just want to see the "green" message, then I can feel really confident to write down the deployment steps. You know, instead of waiting to figure it out at the customer's office. Is there such a way to test?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have used the following steps

```
keytool -keystore mystore -genkey -alias my

keytool -keystore mystore -selfcert -alias my

jarsigner -keystore mystore myapplet.jar my
```